# How to include node_modules in html view

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.1

i am trying to create my first Angular/laravel SPA and i am stuck with trying to get the dependencies attached. I dont know if its proper to copy the entire contents into the public folder.

Any light on how to do this?

i tried to reference the scripts using ./path to script but that didnt seem to work.

```
<!-- Application Dependencies -->
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/build/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/satellizer/satellizer.js"></script>

<!-- Application Scripts -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/authController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/userController.js"></script>
```

i used npm to get my packages so all the files are in the folder in the root of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I fixed using bower instead of npm.

from you command line:

```
npm install bower
bower install angular
....
```

Comment: Respectively i am in the same position, where it simply changed the node folder to bower, but i still dont know how to attach the scripts? What do i need to write in my index.blade.php for the dependencies to attach?